# Reduce dimension: best architecture

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I have a dataset:

```
100 timesteps
10 variables
```

for example,

```
dataset = np.arange(1000).reshape(100,10)
```

The 10 variables are related to each other. So I want to reduce its dimension from 10 to 1. 
Also, 100 time steps are related.

Which deep learning architecture is suitable for it guys?

edit:

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dense

X = np.arange(1000).reshape(100,10)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(input_shape = (100, 10), return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(1))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')

model.fit(???, epochs=50, batch_size=5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to compress your data, the best course of action is to use an autoencoder.

Autoencoder architecture:

Input ---> Encoder (reduces dimensionality of the input) ----> Decoder (tries to recreate input) ---> Lossy version of input

By extracting the trained encoder, we can find a way to represent your data using fewer dimensions.

```
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.models import Model

input = Input(shape=(10,)) #will take an input in shape of (num_samples, 10)

encoded = Dense(1, activation='relu')(input) #returns a 1D vector from input

decoded = Dense(10, activation='sigmoid)(encoded) #tries to recreate input from 1D vector

autoencoder = Model(input, decoded) #input image ---> lossy reconstruction from decoded
```

Now that we have the autoencoder, we need to extract what you really want- the part encoder that reduces the input's dimensionality:

```
encoder = Model(input, encoded) #maps input to reduced-dimension encoded form
```

Compile and train the autoencoder:

```
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse')
X = np.arange(1000).reshape(100, 10)
autoencoder.fit(X, X, batch_size=5, epochs=50)
```

Now you can use the encoder to reduce dimensionality:

```
encoded_form = encoder.predict(<something with shape (samples, 10)>) #outs 1D vector
```

You probably also want the decoder as well. If you are going to use it put this block of code right before you compile and fit the autoencoder:

```
encoded_form = Input(shape=(1,))
decoder_layer = autoencoder.layers[-1]
decoder = Model.(encoded_form, decoder_layer(encoded_form))
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168516/discussion-between-primusa-and-ian).